# SwiftUI preview layout: size that fits does not work

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-previews

I want my preview to only have the size of the view and not show the whole iPhone.
I have already tried it with this code:

```
struct TimerCardView: View {
   
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .padding()
            .background(.gray)
    }
}


struct TimerCardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimerCardView()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

but nothing happened.
What am I doing wrong? I appreciate help

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In Xcode 14+, the default mode for the Preview canvas is live mode, which as you’re seeing places your preview into a device screen context.

Manually adjusting the preview layout requires “selectable” mode, which was the default in previous versions of Xcode. You can switch between modes using the palette at the bottom of the toolbar canvas. For example:

[image: GIF showing difference between preview modes]

Answer (score 29):

Xcode 15 you can do it.

```swift
#Preview(traits: .sizeThatFitsLayout) {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: And in addition to this, I think you have to also press the "selectable" mode like we see in the @ScottM answer. The Lord Always Delivers!

Comment: you need to add `@available(iOS 17, *)` before `#Preview` if you support iOS 16 and iOS 17

Comment: Interestingly, with Xcode 15.1, the preview is broken as long as you select **My Mac** in the preview simulation. Any iOS device works.