# PreviewProvider with new Macro

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, macros

How to use `.previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)` with the new Macro

```
#Preview {
    
    example()
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
}
```

I have tried to see use

```
#Preview {
    
    example()
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
}
```

but it doesn't work beside I have always tried to use this on Xcode 14.3.1 with `PreviewProvider` which has never work for me and I have watched it on YouTube several times seen people using it and it always work for them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77167992/560942

Comment: To summarize the answers to the question that this duplicates: You need to say `#Preview(traits: .sizeThatFitsLayout)` and you need to change the canvas mode from Live to Selectable (using the control at the bottom left of the canvas). If Xcode complains that 'sizeThatFitsLayout' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer, put `@available(iOS 17.0, *)` before `#Preview`.